# Back Pressed from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have read tons of SOF question regarding on the back pressed problems, but somehow I can't find any explicit details on how to do it. Yeah sure implementing it in Activity is easy, but from fragment to activity is quite confusing. Which it's involve on listener which I'm not quite familiar with. Would be a big help someone care to share some solutions. Thanks

Comment: Show what all you've tried

Comment: Well, the concept is wrong. A Fragment lies **inside** an Activity (or against it, if it's a DialogFragment or a PreferenceFragment). So you don't go `from a Fragment to an Activity`, since you are already in the Activity. Just remove the Fragment in `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: There is no need to back from Fragment to Activity ..because your already in activity .Fragment is subset of Activity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code where back button press is recognized:

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
trans.remove(myFrag);
trans.commit();
manager.popBackStack();
```